# filter_var validate url with only host

Tags: php, validation, url, filter-var

I can't for the life of me figure out how to use `filter_var` to validate whether a URL is valid  when it optionally contains the scheme.

So for example, I would like both 
`https://www.google.com` and `www.google.com` to pass validation from `filter_var`.

I've tried using the `FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED` flag exclusively:
`filter_var("www.google.com", FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, ['flags' => FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED])`

and also by negating `FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED` with `FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED`:
`filter_var("www.google.com", FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, ~FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED | FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED)`

and with just negating `FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED`: `filter_var("www.google.com", FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, ~FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED)`

Comment: I'd like to avoid a regex and `filter_var` returns false by default when you don't include the scheme: `filter_var("www.google.com", FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)`. None of the answers in that post help me.

Comment: curl it and check the response.

Comment: Or just prefix with `http` if required.

Comment: @mkaatman Curl will only determine if the URL exists currently. I don't care if the URL exists; I just want to know if its formatting is valid.

Comment: @u_mulder That would require validating the same URL twice with only one minor difference. From my understanding `filter_var` has the ability to do what I'm asking in a single function call.

Comment: I can't find a way to unset flags, and since SCHEME validation is on by default since 5.2.1 .... I would do this some other way. Like as suggested above

Comment: Should it also pass querystring params? `http://example.com?foo=bar`

Comment: @mkaatman Optionally